# How to write a program to draw a tiled picture like this?

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics

I want to write a program to draw a picture which covers a plane with tiled irregular quadrangles, just like this one:

[image]

However, I don't know the relevant algorithms, for example, in which order should I draw the edges?

Could someone point a direction for me?

Comment: [Tesselation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesselation) or tiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies, in my previous answer, I misunderstood the question.

Here is one stab at an algorithm (not necessarily the most optimal way, but *a* way). All you need is the ability to render a polygon and a basic rotation.

[image]

If you don't want the labels to be flipped, draw them separately (the labels can be stored in the vertices, e.g., and rotated with the polygon points, but drawn upright as text).

**Edit**

I received a question about the *"start with an arbitrary polygon"* step. I didn't communicate that step very clearly, as I actually intended to merely suggest an arbitrary polygon from the provided diagram, and not any arbitrary polygon in the world.

However, this should work at least for arbitrary quads, including concave ones, like so:

[image]

I'm afraid I lack the proper background to provide a proof as to why this works, however. Perhaps more mathematically-savvy people can help there with the proof.
I think one way to tackle the proof is to first start with the notion that all tiled edges are manifold -- this is a given considering that we're generating a neighboring polygon at every edge in order to generate the tiled result. Then we might be able to prove that every 2-valence boundary vertex is going to become a 4-valence vertex as a result of this operation (since each of its two edges are going to become manifold, and that introduces two new vertex edges into the mix -- this seems like the hardest part to prove to me). Last step might be to prove that the sum of the angles at each 4-valence vertex will always add up to 360 degrees.

Comment: Will this work for an *arbitrary* quadrilateral?  (It certainly won't work for an arbitrary polygon -- e.g. a concave polygon.)  If so, this seems a surprising fact worthy of explanation (I couldn't find a counterexample in 30s...)

Comment: @j_random_hacker each vertex has four different angles, which must add to 360 in a quad. Looking at the OP's diagram, you can see that edge a,b in one quad is adjacent to edge b,a. So the lengths are the same and the angles add up irrespective of their values, so it will work for any quad.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: That's helpful, thanks.  Based on that, I think it's possible to prove that it's always possible to start from a single quad and repeatedly "wrap" layers of quads around it without ever hitting a "conflict."

Comment: I provided an edit response based on these concerns including a visual result from a concave quad, but I'm afraid I lack the proper background to know how to provide a formal mathematical proof. There I could probably use some help with a better answer to demonstrate the generality of the technique. It would likely involve looking at the interior angles and the angles of the neighboring quads, and proving that first for any vertex, it's going to have a valence of 4, with the sum of the angles always adding up to 360.